# A question about abstract simplicial complexes and discs.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

I find the following definitions in a book about algebraic topology:

> **Definition:** Let $K$ be an abstract simplicial complex.
>
> $(1)$ If $K$ is finite, simply connected and with nonempty boundary, then we say $K$ is a combinatorial closed disk.
>
> $(2)$ If $K$ is infinite, simply connected and without boundary, then we say $K$ is a combinatorial open disk.

Now, I understand that when we talk about a topological disk we refer to a topological space homeomorphic to a disk. What I would like to understand is why the simplicial complex needs to be finite or infinite in the above definitons.

Comment: Does this book have some assumption about the dimension of $K$, for example that it should be 2? The statements don't look correct to me in high dimensions (like 4).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Well, the simplicial complexes have vertices, edges and faces, and are being used to triangulate surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I don't know if this is a yes or no to you question.

Comment: In addition to the 2d assumption, you also have to assume that K is a manifold, otherwise there are easy counter examples. (And, besides, boundary is meaningless for complexes which are not pseudo manifolds.)

Answer (score 2):

As an example on $\mathbb{R}^2$, is there an infinite disk on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is closed (think in terms of compactness)? Think intuitionistically on this one.

Comment: I see. So the finiteness refers to the compactness property of the disks: a open disk is not compact hence there is some covering which does not contain a finite sub covering, and a closed disk is compact hence every covering contains a finite sub covering. Is this correct?

Comment: @ChirsErickson Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ChirsErickson Think of a simplical complex as a topological space, to get a good intuition. Then, the statements become ``obvious''.